# File-Upload not see list file already loaded

Tags: jquery, blueimp

Hallo I'm using jQuery blueimp file upload.
I'd like when upload a new file, in the page not see the list of files already loaded.(file stay in the directory)
Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: you mean like uploading an image and image appear above the button?

Comment: when I open the page for upload a new file, i see all the file inside the directory (already uploaded before)

Comment: Try the script I gave you in the answer .. the file will be displayed in Selector ID "FileUp". otherwise, you need to have a box of directory or path? I still don't get what you mean.

Comment: In the page of upload, I see the list (under the button Add file, Start Upload etcc) of files the uploaded before. I'd like not see this list ma just "blank area". Is your script do? Thks

Comment: ok, wait, I'll do better then. I understand what you mean now.

Comment: Pls see the updated I make it for you :p

Comment: thanks gkol! Sorry but I can't do works.... :( can you put the code in the original file?... index.html of jQuery blueimp. If you want post the code

Answer (score 0):

Here, this script upload your file directly without warning.I've tested it works fine.

**UPDATED:**

```
<script>
    var oFReader = new FileReader();
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("file").files[0]);
        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
        document.getElementById("fileUp").src = oFREvent.target.result;
    };
</script>
<?php
if ($mypath = opendir('myfiledir/')) {
    while (false !== ($filedispl = readdir($mypath))) {
        if ($filedispl != "." && $filedispl != "..") {
            echo "<ul class='filelist'>LIST FILES:";
            echo "<li>$entry</li>";
            echo "</ul>";
        }
    }
}   
?>
<br />
<b>Currently Uploaded:</b><br />
<div id="fileUp"><!--file will be displayed here--></div>
<input id="file" type="file" name="file" onchange="myfile();" class="btn btn-default" />
<script>
function displ_myfile() {
    var oFReader = new FileReader();
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("file").files[0]);
        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
            document.getElementById("fileUp").src = oFREvent.target.result;
    };
};
</script>
```

This following tutorial is also good for better development:

http://www.raymondcamden.com/2013/09/10/Adding-a-file-display-list-to-a-multifile-upload-HTML-control